# Ajax call in Django Rest Framework using array

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django Rest Framework,running v. 3.5.4 (Django 1.10.6) and I have implemented a simple model (Test) and its ModelSerializer.

This model has a manyTomany relationship with another one, but this is not the problem right now. The thing is that I need to pass an array of ids from my ajax call, to add to my manytomany relationship.

Ajax call is like this:

```
data = {
     address: 'foo'
     owner: [1,2]
}

ajax = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res){
        console.log(res)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error,'erro')
    }
 })
```

My view is like this:

```
class Test(APIView):


    def post(self, request, format=None):

        print(request.data)
        print([(x,y) for x,y in request.data.items()])

        serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So, the print outputs from my view are the problem:

Output from `print(request.data)` is `<QueryDict: {'address': ['foo'], 'owner[]': ['1', '2']}>`

So far so good!

Output from `print([(x,y) for x,y in request.data.items()])` is `[('address', 'foo'), ('owner[]', '2')]`

Whaaaaat?

So, the array became a string with the last item only. What happened?

Apart from that, the is.valid() method seems to erase the array. I made a custom create method in my serializer:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
owner = OwnerSerializer(many=True)
class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = ('id','address','owner')


def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)

    return none
```

Output from print is `{'address': 'foo', 'owner': []}`  And no error raised!

So, what is going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@list_route(methods=['POST'], permission_classes=[AllowAny])
def test(self, request):
    print(request.data)
    print([(x, y) for x, y in request.data.items()])
    print(request.data['owner'])
    import ast
    for x in ast.literal_eval(request.data['owner']):
        print(x)
    return Response("...")

<QueryDict: {'address': ['foo'], 'owner': ['[1,2]']}>
[('address', 'foo'), ('owner', '[1,2]')]
[1,2]
1
2
```

Ajax try:

```
data = {
 address: 'foo'
 owner: '[1,2]'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i solved this problem providing

```
serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data.dict())
```

instead o f

```
serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.data)
```

I supose this inconvenient will be solved in a future release.